# Management of CI / CD vuejs deployments

Tags: node.js, vue.js, deployment, gitlab, environment-variables

I need help with deploying **vuejs** project using *CI / CD* **gitlab**.

in this case I have 3 file **environments**:

1. .env.development.local
2. .env.staging.local
3. .env.production.local

And I'm here using a different **baseHref** / **publicPath**:

1. / development
2. / stage
3. / production

In this stage I follow the tutorial [Here.](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2017/09/12/vuejs-app-gitlab/)

but I am still confused about how I deployed using a different env.

Usually I use the command:

1. Staging

> npm run build -- --mode stage

2. Production

> npm run build -- --mode production

Here is an example of the **env** that I made:

```js
# Environment Local

NODE_ENV=development
BASE_URL = /development/
VUE_APP_TITLE=Website (development)
VUE_APP_END_POINT='http://localhost:8000/api/v1/'
VUE_APP_CLIENT_ID = 12341
VUE_APP_CLIENT_SECRET = 'asdASD1123s'
VUE_APP_SCOPE = '*'
VUE_APP_BASE_URL_LINK = 'http://localhost:8080'
VUE_APP_VERSION =
```

And this is the **vue.config.js** file that I have:

```js
process.env.VUE_APP_VERSION = require('./package.json').version

module.exports = {
    publicPath: process.env.BASE_URL,
    "transpileDependencies": [
        "vuetify"
    ]
}
```

branch that I made:

1. test
2. development
3. master

In gitlab-ci.yml:

```
build site:
  image: node:6
  stage: build
  script:
    - npm install --progress=false
    - npm run build
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 1 week
    paths:
      - dist

unit test:
  image: node:6
  stage: test
  script:
    - npm install --progress=false
    - npm run unit

deploy:
  image: alpine
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - apk add --no-cache rsync openssh
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" >> ~/.ssh/id_dsa
    - chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_dsa
    - echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config
    - rsync -rav --delete dist/ user@server.com:/var/www/website/
```

with the configuration of gitlab-ci.yml above I can only deploy local env.

I hope someone wants to share their knowledge and experience about *CI / CD* deploy **vuejs**. Or give some *CI / CD* **vuejs** tutorial references multiple **environment**.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I found a dockerfile in my projet if it's can help you :

```
FROM node:12.16.1 AS builder
RUN mkdir /app
COPY *.json /app/
COPY src /app/src
WORKDIR /app
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:1.15.8
COPY --from=builder /app/dist/ /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80:80
ENTRYPOINT ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Don't forget to use multi stages docker ;)